# Using both Caller-Allowable-Codebase and Trusted-Library in Java manifest

Tags: java, manifest

In the last version of Java, only one of the two could be used Caller-Allowable-Codebase being the preferred parameter.

Does anyone know if this has changed since it was hinted in the 1.7.045 that in the future both parameters could coexist ?

Answer (score 0):

The are many contradictions between different updates in Java 7. So, I created several JAR files with different attributes for different Java versions, and created a server-side script (in php in my case) that analyzes "user_agent" http header from Java plugin when it requests the a jar file. The script returns the approprite jar file depending on Java version or update. Then I specified the script name as the archive attribute in HTML page. The solution doesn't look as perfect from maintenance point of view (too many jars) but reliable.